# Creating a grid of objects

Tags: javascript, processing, interactive, p5.js

Can someone please point me in the right direction. I want to create a grid of objects in p5js, for instance a grid of squares. I want to be able click on any particular square and for it to have an interactive element i.e it moves or changes colour for instance. Now, in order for this to happen and to specify any particular square on the grid, am i right in thinking i need to use a 2d array? Also What, if any other method, could i use to achieve similar results? I can already create a simple grid of squares but am unable to access them individually.
thanks in advance,
g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using a 2D array is the correct approach. However, as in p5.js the shapes you draw are not permanent, but rather get redrawn on every frame, you have to take care yourself that you can access them. Usually this should be done by creating pure JavaScript objects with all the necessary properties, collecting all those in an array and then use this array to draw all the shapes each frame.

Daniel Shiffman has some good tutorials on exactly this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGkSHeEZLMU&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA&index=22 . This and the following tutorials should get you started.

Comment: even a 1D array of objects with events handlers/ids could work, but I a 2D array may be more intuitive for a grid when getting started with the language (+1)